# Why Vue data is not updating int his case

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am struggling to understand Vue fully. Say I have:

```js
<!--store.js-->
export default {
  x:{
    p:{},
  },
}
```

```html
<!--text.vue-->
<template>
  <div class="test-comp">Test component</div>
</template>

<script>
import store from '../store';
export default {
   data(){
     return {
       p:store.x.p,
     };
   },
   methods:{
      loadData(){
        store.x.p.a='some data';
      },
   },
   mounted(){
     this.loadData();
   }
}
</script>
```

In the above   `this.p` has a value of `{}` i.e empty object, after running the file. However, in Javascript without Vue:  `let p=store.x.p` is a reference and so `p` references the same value as `store.x.p`

What am I doing wrong in Vue?

Sorry all, I must be making a mistake somewhere else as this works on fiddle.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You should commit mutations to change the store state (e.g., `store.commit('update')`.

Comment: @SebastianRichner my aim is a humble and simple one: update this.p from {} to {a:'some data'} by changing store.x.p which is trivial without Vue. I do not use Vue's state management as its just too much for this humble aim,

Comment: In the store you have `p` and then `x` inside it, but in the code you are doing `store.x.p` which is vice versa

Comment: @sorry that's an error in reproducing my code here in stack, i will update

Comment: Sorry all, I must be making a mistake somewhere else as this works on fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Vue State Management exists for a set of reasons and making the state variables reactive is one of them. I suggest reading/watching [this explanation on the official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

If you want to implement your own vanilla store, you can update your store with `Vue.set` or `this.$set`.

Comment: I am trying to to understand what is happening. Does vue remove references to objects and replace them by their values in 'data' property. You are giving me links on reactivity. This is not really about reactivity, rather references

Comment: Sorry all, I must be making a mistake somewhere else as this works on fiddle